# Winginx Faild to start on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, winginx

I just installed Winginx on fresh Windows 10 and nginx never start.

In log I have found:

```
CreateFile() "C:\Winginx/temp/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Has anyone met with such problem before?

Comment: Apparently, a lot of apps crash on win10 :(

Comment: I had this problem and resolved it by reinstalling Winginx... then just copied my config over to the new install location.

Comment: Might be missing dependancies? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49951609/1689770

Answer (score -1):

I found my solution by giving up and used WampDeveloper Pro Trial. Their installation goes through a check list of items to see if it will cause any problem. And the main problem that came out is the Host file is read only. Which is caused by many Firewall or Antispyware software. In my case it was Spybot.

I simply disabled the read only on my host file, and ran it again and it worked.

Although I got Winginx to work, it may not only be the host file causing the issue. It could be many more, but my WampDeveloper Pro Trial helped fix things I guess, it even check if there are other services uses Port 80 and 443 and disabled them for example. So now, my Winginx is working, that I can turn on and off and so is my WampDeveloper Pro trial, that I turn on and off. So I simply turn one of them on when I need it.

Comment: See also Laragon,Wamp, or XAMPP