# Winginx not working on server 2012

Tags: winginx

After winginx installing the on server 2012. Following errors

mysqld.exe:
[image: mysqld.exe]

mysqld.exe has stopped:
[image: mysqld.exe has stopped]

php-cgi.exe system error:
[image: php-cgi.exe system error]

Comment: Please edit your question and write the errors as text. Linked images make it painful for anyone to read your question. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this problem the other night. I essentially had to install microsoft C++ redistrubtables for 2008 - 2013 (x64) AND (x86)